# Vimperator for all modes not work

Tags: vimperator

`map <C-a>  <Esc>` not work in vimperator  ( I can't exit from insert mode ).
 But `imap <C-a>  <Esc>` Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because just as in Vim `map` is for mapping sequences in normal and visual modes, I guess. I would suggest you to check the `:help :map` again.